# Split a Column of DenseMatrices into separate rows (with a Vector in each row)

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a Column in a `pyspark.sql.DataFrame` that is of type `matrix`.

Every cell in this column is a `DenseMatrix` of shape `(numRows, 268)`

i.e. the number of rows from cell to cell will vary, but the number of columns will always be 268.

I want to split up all the rows in all the matrices in this column such that each row in the produced dataframe will be a vector.

For example, how would I convert the following:

```
|groups|windows                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    |
+------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|1     |0.0                 0.0                 1.383419689119171   ... (268 total)
0.0                 1.0308333333333333  1.0                 ...
0.0                 1.0714285714285714  1.0                 ...
0.0                 1.241112828438949   1.0                 ...
0.0                 1.01                1.0212464589235128  ...
0.0                 0.0                 1.0303994011640099  ...
0.0                 1.0310714270488266  0.0                 ...
0.0                 1.7106598984771573  0.0                 ...
0.0                 1.0                 1.7657142857142856  ...
0.0                 1.3483709273182958  1.7071428571428573  ...
0.0                 1.4608788853161845  1.2461538461538462  ...
0.0                 1.0                 0.0                 ...
0.0                 1.0                 0.0                 ...
1.6600496277915633  1.0                 1.0                 ...
1.3537936913895994  1.812121212121212   1.2403100775193798  ...
0.0                 1.6721590909090909  1.0                 ...
1.6479591836734695  0.0                 0.0                 ...
0.0                 1.075               0.0                 ...
1.2246376811594204  0.0                 0.0                 ...
1.0                 1.659994867847062   1.0                 ...
1.0                 0.0                 1.5507936E9         ...
0.0                 1.0                 0.0                 ...
1.6974358974358972  0.0                 0.0                 ...|
|2     |0.0                 0.0                 1.4455958549222798  ... (268 total)
0.0                 1.02875             1.0                 ...
0.0                 1.0714285714285714  1.0                 ...
0.0                 1.2179289026275115  1.0                 ...
0.0                 1.01                1.0191218130311614  ...
0.0                 0.0                 1.028490828331661   ...
0.0                 1.028214284187194   0.0                 ...
0.0                 1.7309644670050761  0.0                 ...
0.0                 1.0                 1.7885714285714287  ...
0.0                 1.3525480367585632  1.7285714285714286  ...
0.0                 1.4683815648445875  1.2153846153846155  ...
0.0                 1.0                 0.0                 ...
0.0                 1.0                 0.0                 ...
1.6972704714640199  1.0                 1.0                 ...
1.3580562659846547  1.8242424242424242  1.2170542635658914  ...
0.0                 1.6971590909090908  1.0                 ...
1.663265306122449   0.0                 0.0                 ...
0.0                 1.0964285714285715  0.0                 ...
1.2028985507246377  0.0                 0.0                 ...
1.0                 1.6782140107775212  1.0                 ...
1.0                 0.0                 1.5507936E9         ...
0.0                 1.0                 0.0                 ...
1.7282051282051283  0.0                 0.0                 ...|
+------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
only showing top 2 rows
```

To something like:

```
|groups|windows                                                                  
+------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------
|1     |0.0,                 0.0,                 1.383419689119171,   ... (268 total)
+------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------
|1     |0.0,                 1.0308333333333333,  1.0,                 ...
+------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------
|1     |0.0,                 1.0714285714285714,  1.0,                 ...
+------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------
|1     |0.0,                 1.241112828438949,   1.0,                 ...
+------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------
|1     |0.0,                 1.01,                1.0212464589235128,  ...
+------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------
|1     |0.0,                 0.0,                 1.0303994011640099,  ...
+------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------
|1     |0.0,                 1.0310714270488266,  0.0,                 ...
+------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------
|1     |0.0,                 1.7106598984771573,  0.0,                 ...
+------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------
|1     |0.0,                 1.0,                 1.7657142857142856,  ...
+------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------
|1     |0.0,                 1.3483709273182958,  1.7071428571428573,  ...
+------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------
|1     |0.0,                 1.4608788853161845,  1.2461538461538462,  ...
+------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------
|1     |0.0,                 1.0,                 0.0,                 ...
+------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------
|1     |0.0,                 1.0,                 0.0,                 ...
+------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------
|1     |1.6600496277915633,  1.0,                 1.0,                 ...
+------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------
|1     |1.3537936913895994,  1.812121212121212,   1.2403100775193798,  ...
+------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------
|1     |0.0,                 1.6721590909090909,  1.0,                 ...
+------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------
|1     |1.6479591836734695,  0.0,                 0.0,                 ...
+------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------
|1     |0.0,                 1.075,               0.0,                 ...
+------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------
|1     |1.2246376811594204,  0.0,                 0.0,                 ...
+------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------
|1     |1.0,                 1.659994867847062,   1.0,                 ...
+------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------
|1     |1.0,                 0.0,                 1.5507936E9,         ...
+------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------
|1     |0.0,                 1.0,                 0.0,                 ...
+------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------
|1     |1.6974358974358972,  0.0,                 0.0,                 ...|
+------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------
|2     |0.0,                 0.0,                 1.4455958549222798,  ... (268 total)
+------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------
|2     |0.0,                 1.02875,             1.0,                 ...
+------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------
|2     |0.0,                 1.0714285714285714,  1.0,                 ...
+------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------
|2     |0.0,                 1.2179289026275115,  1.0,                 ...
+------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------
|2     |0.0,                 1.01,                1.0191218130311614,  ...
+------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------
|2     |0.0,                 0.0,                 1.028490828331661,   ...
+------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------
|2     |0.0,                 1.028214284187194,   0.0,                 ...
+------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------
|2     |0.0,                 1.7309644670050761,  0.0,                 ...
+------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------
|2     |0.0,                 1.0,                 1.7885714285714287,  ...
+------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------
|2     |0.0,                 1.3525480367585632,  1.7285714285714286,  ...
+------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------
|2     |0.0,                 1.4683815648445875,  1.2153846153846155,  ...
+------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------
|2     |0.0,                 1.0,                 0.0,                 ...
+------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------
|2     |0.0,                 1.0,                 0.0,                 ...
+------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------
|2     |1.6972704714640199,  1.0,                 1.0,                 ...
+------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------
|2     |1.3580562659846547,  1.8242424242424242,  1.2170542635658914,  ...
+------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------
|2     |0.0,                 1.6971590909090908,  1.0,                 ...
+------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------
|2     |1.663265306122449,   0.0,                 0.0,                 ...
+------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------
|2     |0.0,                 1.0964285714285715,  0.0,                 ...
+------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------
|2     |1.2028985507246377,  0.0,                 0.0,                 ...
+------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------
|2     |1.0,                 1.6782140107775212,  1.0,                 ...
+------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------
|2     |1.0,                 0.0,                 1.5507936E9,         ...
+------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------
|2     |0.0,                 1.0,                 0.0,                 ...
+------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------
|2     |1.7282051282051283,  0.0,                 0.0,                 ...|
+------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------
+------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------
only showing top 2 rows
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

**EDIT_1**

I'll reiterate that I start with a [`DenseMatrix`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.0/api/python/_modules/pyspark/mllib/linalg.html#DenseMatrix). I was also able to 'solve' my problem by using the `explode` function, but I had to:

1) cast the `windows` column to string:

```py
def stringify_matrices(x):
    arr = x.toArray()
    l = arr.tolist()
    return l

stringify_matrices_udf = udf(lambda y: stringify_matrices(y),) 

expanded = \
    extracted.withColumn('expanded',
                        stringify_matrices_udf('windows')
                        )
```

2) parse that string to an array of strings (with each string representing a vector)

```py
def parse_matrices(x):
    from ast import literal_eval
    t = literal_eval(str(x))
    str_arr = [str(a) for a in t]
    return str_arr

parse_matrices_udf = udf(lambda y: parse_matrices(y), ArrayType(StringType()))

parsed = \
    expanded.withColumn('parsed',
                        parse_matrices_udf('expanded')
                        )
```

3) `explode`ing

```py
parsed = parsed.withColumn('exploded', explode(parsed.parsed)).select('groups', 'exploded')
```

4) casting to `ArrayType(DoubleType()))`

```py
def convert_to_double(x):
    str_arr = x.replace('[','').replace(']','').split(',')
    flt_arr = [float(a) for a in str_arr]
    return flt_arr

convert_to_double_udf = udf(lambda y: convert_to_double(y), ArrayType(DoubleType()))

converted = parsed.withColumn('feature_vector', convert_to_double_udf('exploded'))
```

The above works, but I feel as if there is a better way to approach this.

**EDIT_2** 
@mayanak agrawal 
Thanks for your answer!
I guess in response, I would ask:

How to convert from a `DenseMatrix` column:
e.g.

```py
dm_df = sqlContext.createDataFrame([
        (1, 
         DenseMatrix(numRows=3, numCols=4, values=[2,4,2,5,30,4,2,5,30,4,2,5], isTransposed=True)),
        (2, 
         DenseMatrix(numRows=2, numCols=4, values=[2,1,3,7,2,4,2,9], isTransposed=True)),
        (3, 
         DenseMatrix(numRows=4, numCols=4, values=[2,4,2,5,2,4,2,5,2,1,3,7,2,1,3,7], isTransposed=True))],
        ['groups', 'windows'])
dm_df.show()
```

```
+------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|groups|windows                                                                            |
+------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|1     |2.0   4.0  2.0  5.0  
30.0  4.0  2.0  5.0  
30.0  4.0  2.0  5.0                    |
|2     |2.0  1.0  3.0  7.0  
2.0  4.0  2.0  9.0                                            |
|3     |2.0  4.0  2.0  5.0  
2.0  4.0  2.0  5.0  
2.0  1.0  3.0  7.0  
2.0  1.0  3.0  7.0  |
+------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

To a column of 2D floats (as seen in your example):

```py
arr_df = sqlContext.createDataFrame([
        (1, [[2,4,2,5],[30,4,2,5],[30,4,2,5]]),
        (2, [[2,1,3,7],[2,4,2,9]]),
        (3, [[2,4,2,5],[2,4,2,5],[2,1,3,7],[2,1,3,7]])],
        ['groups', 'windows'])
arr_df.show()
```

```
+------+--------------------------------------------------------+
|groups|windows                                                 |
+------+--------------------------------------------------------+
|1     |[[2, 4, 2, 5], [30, 4, 2, 5], [30, 4, 2, 5]]            |
|2     |[[2, 1, 3, 7], [2, 4, 2, 9]]                            |
|3     |[[2, 4, 2, 5], [2, 4, 2, 5], [2, 1, 3, 7], [2, 1, 3, 7]]|
+------+--------------------------------------------------------+
```

Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was not able to create your exact sample dataframe. Hence I created a smaller version of it. Let me know if any changes required.

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df = sql.createDataFrame([
        (1, [[2,4,2,5],[30,4,2,5],[30,4,2,5]]),
        (2, [[2,1,3,7],[2,4,2,9]]),
        (3, [[2,4,2,5,3],[2,4,2,5],[2,1,3,7],[2,1,3,7]])],
        ['groups', 'windows'])
```

By exploding on the `'windows'` column, we get the desired result.

```py
df = df.select(['groups', F.explode(F.col('windows')).alias('windows')])
```

This gives output as,

```py
+------+---------------+
|groups|        windows|
+------+---------------+
|     1|   [2, 4, 2, 5]|
|     1|  [30, 4, 2, 5]|
|     1|  [30, 4, 2, 5]|
|     2|   [2, 1, 3, 7]|
|     2|   [2, 4, 2, 9]|
|     3|[2, 4, 2, 5, 3]|
|     3|   [2, 4, 2, 5]|
|     3|   [2, 1, 3, 7]|
|     3|   [2, 1, 3, 7]|
+------+---------------+
```

EDIT:

I was directly able to explode it after converting it to list. No need to convert to strings. Just give the data type in `stringify_matrices_udf`.

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

from pyspark.sql.types import *

def stringify_matrices(x):
    arr = x.toArray()
    l = arr.tolist()
    print l
    return l


df = sql.createDataFrame([
        (1, 
         DenseMatrix(numRows=3, numCols=4, values=[2,4,2,5,30,4,2,5,30,4,2,5], isTransposed=True)),
        (2, 
         DenseMatrix(numRows=2, numCols=4, values=[2,1,3,7,2,4,2,9], isTransposed=True)),
        (3, 
         DenseMatrix(numRows=4, numCols=4, values=[2,4,2,5,2,4,2,5,2,1,3,7,2,1,3,7], isTransposed=True))],
        ['groups', 'windows'])

stringify_matrices_udf = F.udf(lambda y: stringify_matrices(y),ArrayType(ArrayType(FloatType()))) 

df = \
    df.withColumn('expanded',
                        stringify_matrices_udf('windows')
                        ) \
      .select(['groups', F.explode(F.col('expanded')).alias('windows')])

df.show()
```

This gives,

```py
+------+--------------------+
|groups|             windows|
+------+--------------------+
|     1|[2.0, 4.0, 2.0, 5.0]|
|     1|[30.0, 4.0, 2.0, ...|
|     1|[30.0, 4.0, 2.0, ...|
|     2|[2.0, 1.0, 3.0, 7.0]|
|     2|[2.0, 4.0, 2.0, 9.0]|
|     3|[2.0, 4.0, 2.0, 5.0]|
|     3|[2.0, 4.0, 2.0, 5.0]|
|     3|[2.0, 1.0, 3.0, 7.0]|
|     3|[2.0, 1.0, 3.0, 7.0]|
+------+--------------------+
```

Comment: thank you very much @mayanak!  
  
Relatedly, do you think using the `stringify_matrices_udf` as a `pandas_udf` would improve performance?

Comment: Do you mean you want to use it on a Pandas dataframe instead of Spark? It depends on how big your data is.

Comment: No, @mayanak, this [databricks blog](https://databricks.com/blog/2017/10/30/introducing-vectorized-udfs-for-pyspark.html) showcases enhanced performance using `pandas_udf` when compared to `udf` - I was wondering whether you were familiar with them perhaps.`pandas_udf` seem to be optimized to perform _scalar_ operations, so I was considering using them for the operation described above.